# AHK - logar e avisar com beep

Tags: autohotkey

Boas.

Tenho um script em AHK que precisava de melhorar, mas está para além do que consigo fazer.
A questão é simples, pingar um website e em caso de falhar, apresentar duas informações.
Uma delas, a última hora e data que esteve online.
A segunda, avisar com um beep de X em X de tempo que está offline.

Tenho este script (google.com utilizado apenas para demo) e funciona para verificar, com o GUI a apresentar a informação.
Como poderei implementar isso neste script?

Obrigado e abraço!

```
Gui, +AlwaysOnTop

Gui, add, edit, vedit1 w400 h200 ;Remember asigning the variable

Gui, show

gosub, refresh

Settimer, refresh, 1000

return



refresh:

    Settimer, refresh, off

    Runwait %comspec% /c ping google.com >ping.txt,,hide

    FileRead, file, ping.txt

    FormatTime, now, , HH:mm:ss

    GuiControl,,edit1,%now%`n%file%

    Settimer, refresh, 1000

return

ExitApp

esc::ExitApp
```

Versão 2:

```
Gui, +AlwaysOnTop
Gui, add, edit, vedit1 w400 h200
Gui, Show, , Checker Tool ; Create and display the GUI
gosub, refresh
Settimer, refresh, 1000
    return
        refresh:
            Settimer, refresh, off
            Runwait %comspec% /c ping google.com >ping.txt,,hide
            FileRead, file, ping.txt
            FormatTime, now, , HH:mm:ss
            GuiControl,,edit1,%now%`n%file%
            fileread, StrTemp, ping.txt

            if RegExMatch(StrTemp, "Average = (\d+)")
                Sleep 1000

            else

                SoundBeep, 750, 2000
                FileAppend, %A_YYYY%-%A_MM%-%A_DD% %A_Hour%:%A_Min%:%A_Sec%`n, downtime.txt

            Settimer, refresh, 1000
        return
    ExitApp
esc::ExitApp
```

Comment: Eu sou bastante novo em programação, e realmente não tenho ideia do que possa fazer para ter a solução, estou a procura de ideias nesse sentido, ou que me possam apontar na direcção correcta, e eu posteriormente sigo-a :)
Se realmente não pode ser assim, obrigado na mesma :D
Abraço

Comment: Nem é questão de "poder ser", mas se ao menos desse uma noção do tipo "localizei tal coisa na documentação, inseri desta forma" (põe o código na pergunta) "e o resultado foi tal", facilitaria pro pessoal te orientar e te ensinar o que falta. Da forma como está, não vejo outro caminho senão alguém ter que fazer por você. Se [edit] e descrever melhor qual o próximo passo que precisa dar e a dificuldade, aumenta muito a chance de uma resposta útil.

Comment: Compreendo, não estou aqui a "chuchar a teta" :)
Neste momento já consegui fazer mais ou menos o que queria..
Já loga o downtime no ficheiro aparte (vai registando os checks), e já avisa com beep. (versão 2 em cima)

Comment: lembre que você pode [edit] a pergunta a qq momento para adicionar mais detalhes, trechos de código etc (e tirar duvidas até aqui pelos comentários).

Comment: Ah, e se chegar numa resposta, pode postar no campo abaixo também, explicando como solucionou, se quiser deixar a solução como referência para outros colegas

Comment: Correcto :)
Mas aqui não tem muita ciência, foi só ler o manual e googlar exemplos.
Para os próximos já vou explicar com mais detalhe :)